# How to turn off laravel internal logging

Tags: laravel, logging, laravel-artisan

I've a laravel app in which I log messages (i'm using stderr as output) so the log messages appear. the problem is that laravel internally logs so many messages that my log almost lost in those internal messages. for instance, this is the output in which the first message is the one that I have using `Log::warning()`

```
  local.WARNING: Temporal already present, cannot add again, 422, #0 app/Http/Controllers/DependencyController.php(34): App\Http\Services\DependencyService->add().  

   WARN  #1 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(54): App\Http\Controllers\DependencyController->add().  

   WARN  #2 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(43): Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction().  

   WARN  #3 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(259): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch().  

   WARN  #4 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(205): Illuminate\Routing\Route->runController().  

   WARN  #5 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(799): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run().  

   WARN  #6 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(141): Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}().  

   WARN  #7 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(50): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}().  

   WARN  #8 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings->handle().  

   WARN  #9 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php(159): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}().  

   WARN  #10 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php(125): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests->handleRequest().  

   WARN  #11 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php(87): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests->handleRequestUsingNamedLimiter().  

   WARN  #12 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests->handle().  

   WARN  #13 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}().  

   WARN  #14 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(798): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then().  

   WARN  #15 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(777): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack().  

   WARN  #16 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(741): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRoute().  

   WARN  #17 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(730): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute().  

   WARN  #18 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(200): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch().  

   WARN  #19 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(141): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}().  

   WARN  #20 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}().  

   WARN  #21 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php(31): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle().  

   WARN  #22 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull->handle().  

   WARN  #23 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}().  

   WARN  #24 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php(40): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle().  

   WARN  #25 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings->handle().  

   WARN  #26 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}().  

   WARN  #27 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize->handle().  

   WARN  #28 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(99): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}().  

   WARN  #29 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle().  

   WARN  #30 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/HandleCors.php(62): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}().  

   WARN  #31 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors->handle().  

   WARN  #32 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php(39): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}().  

   WARN  #33 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies->handle().  

   WARN  #34 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}().  

   WARN  #35 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(175): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then().  

   WARN  #36 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(144): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter().  

   WARN  #37 public/index.php(51): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle().  

   WARN  #38 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/resources/server.php(16): require_once('...').  

   WARN  #39 {main} .  

  2023-11-12 12:48:45 ................................................... ~ 0s
```

I have already tried this in the app/providers/appServiceprovider.php and have also set the APP_DEBUG to false

```
public function boot(): void
{
    //
    error_reporting(1);
    error_clear_last();
}
```

Is there a way to turn off laravel internal logging so that only my log messages appear in the output?

Comment: do you want a permanent change then you can i guess change it in `config/logging.php` in that you can change the values of levels

Comment: Turning off logging in general is not a good idea. If your app logs many errors, you should rather evaluate and fix them.

Answer (score 0):

You can create in your `config/logging.php` a separate log channel

```
'my_app_channel' => [
    'driver' => 'single',
    'path' => storage_path('logs/my_app.log'),
    'level' => 'warning',
],
```

Send your warning on this new channel :

```
Log::channel('my_app_channel')->warning('Your message');
```

And consult the result in your logs/my_app.log file.

You can change the driver/channels/path to fit your app / needs cf :

- https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/logging#configuration

---

Or if it's one-off/temporary, you could adjust the log level of your existing channel up to `error` instead of `warning` and use `log::error` instead